# prevent duplicated values mongodb find query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

(javascript)

hello, i have a mongodb collection who have this schema:

```js
{
  _id: "any",
  ids: {
     user: "some value who can repeat" // and more keys but i will use this key here
  },
  time: 400 // can vary
}
```

I need to get some documents from this collection, filter to "time less than 700" and dont repeat the key "user"

I tried to use js tools for this, but in only 1 find query i get +900 documents

```js
const ids = [];

const query = (await Personagens.find({ time: { $lt: 700 }}).sort({ time: 1 }))
.filter(x => {
    if (!ids.includes(x.ids.user)) {
        ids.push(x.ids.user);
        return true;
    }
}).slice(0, 50)
```

[the output who shows +900 documents in 1 query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cxwg.png)

so i want to know if has some mongo db operator to filter repeated keys (the key `ids.user`) and get only 50 documents (obs: i use mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      time: {
        "$gt": 700
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$ids.user",
      "doc": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "doc": {
        "$first": "$doc"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$doc"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G-kwuYzlUIX)